# get the base price and final price with out html in collection Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have an issue that i am getting the base price and final price in html while rendering collection,I need a fix so that i can get the base price and final price separately in magento 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get price by using this:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
/*I am getting collection of 2 products i.e.   ->setPageSize(2)  */
$collection = $productCollection->create()->addFinalPrice()->addMinimalPrice()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->setPageSize(2)->load();

foreach ($collection as $key => $product){
      $pp = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product['entity_id']);
      echo $pp->getFinalPrice();
      echo $pp->getPrice(); 
}
```

Comment: @M Jatinder Saini , Thanks  !!! for this code

Comment: @user2428249 Glad it's helped